# Loading dialog doesnt paints while loading other things

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to do some kind of load screen while a heavy load code its working but i can't make the loading screen gets painted, it just have it's inside in white instread of show it's label of "Loading please wait"

It's seems that the overload of the main program doesnt allows the other dialog (launched with a thread to allow me to make it modal but the code go on in background) get painted or something like that

Thank you

Comment: Can anyone help me to show that loading window please? Im talking in java SE, sorry

Answer (score 2):

The typical problem is that the code is doing a long running task on the EDT.  The solution is "*Don't* block the EDT".

See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) lesson of the Java Tutorials for further details.

Comment: I have been using a SwingWorker, but it makes the work go like  times slower, is there any way to make it work faster, im totally sure that my code is already as fast as posible, i load from a txt 5000 lines per second

Comment: I think we'll need to see code.  And by 'code' I mean an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I find that when the question being asked contains code, then the answer usually contains code.